# Always display web pages in a specific language, even if it has multiple localizations, in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-localization

I am working on a project where I am developing a web application using ASP.NET Core 5 MVC (Visual Studio 2019). At first, the client wanted the application to have support for several languages, but now, for the first version, only the Spanish language is necessary.

The project is prepared to have multiple languages and as I was developing it, I created the `x.en.resx` and `x.es.resx` files. The problem is that the application is always displayed in English, obteniendo los textos de los ficheros `x.en.resx`.

This is the part where I configure the localization in the `ConfigureServices()` method of the `Startup.cs` file.

```
services.AddLocalization();
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("es")
    };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "es", uiCulture: "es");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new MyCustomRequestCultureProvider());
});
```

`MyCustomRequestCultureProvider` class:

```
public class MyCustomRequestCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
    public override async Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        return new ProviderCultureResult("es");
    }
}
```

I don't care if the language comes in the url, in the Accept field of the request or in the cookie, the response must be in Spanish. But even if you define that only the Spanish language is supported, it is displayed in English.

Since I already have all the `x.en.resx` files created, I don't want to delete them, because I will need them in the future.

Comment: According to the microsoft documentation you should configure your localization before you add `services.AddMvc()`. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#localization-middleware)

Comment: Will [this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/611607/how-to-add-custom-culture-ex-en-mxenglish-mexico-i.html) help you?

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. @Chen, your link has been helpful, I needed to put the ```#region snippet2``` code from the first answer.